# How to improve robustness of cdk snapshot tests to be less sensitive to order of properties in synthesized stacks?

Tags: aws-cdk

I am using cdk and creating tests using the snapshot testing approach.

```js
test("LoadBalancer Stack Snapshot", () => {
  expect(
    YAML.stringify(Template.fromStack(stack), null, {
      singleQuote: true,
    })
  ).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

A problem I have is that each time the aws-cdk-lib dependency is updated the new snapshots never match the existing snapshots.  One of the differences is the order the properties are serialized.  It seems like some resources serialize the properties in alphabetical order which is good as it is more consistent, while for other resources, the properties get serialized in a non deterministic way.  Is there any guidance on how to make the snapshot tests more robust and not as sensitive to changes to things like property order when synthesized ( template.fromStack(stack) is executed).   Thank-you.

I tried using the sortMapEntries: true property for the YAML.stringify.

```js
test("LoadBalancer Stack Snapshot", () => {
  expect(
    YAML.stringify(Template.fromStack(stack), null, {
      sortMapEntries: true,
      singleQuote: true,
    })
  ).toMatchSnapshot();
```

however this did not sort the properties for the aws resources.  It only sorted the higher level template properties which are: "Outputs", "Parameters", "Resources"

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could it be that your yaml parser is reordering the object keys, not the CDK?  Try snapshotting as JSON, without the yaml step:  `Template.fromStack(stack).toJSON()`.

Comment: @fedonev yes, It appears the Template.fromStack(stack) outputs json and the properties do appear to be in alphabetical order.  The requirement I have is to out the snapshot file in yaml format. I ended up using the js-yaml library (https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml0 and specifically the `dump` function which as a `sortKeys: true` option which seems to do the trick.